# Alternative Definition for the Derivative

Tags: derivatives, definition

In one class, we said that a function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at $x_0$ if there exists a map $g : U\subset \mathbb{R} \to L(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$ continuous at $x_0$ such that
$$
f(x) = f(x_0) + g(x)(x - x_0)
$$
where $U$ is a neighborhood of $x_0$. This is obviously just a restatement of the usual definition of a derivative with $f'(x_0) = g(x_0)$, but it has distinct advantages. For example, the proof of the chain rule becomes much clearer.

Can we play a similar game in multiple variables? That is, given a function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$, can we say that it is differentiable at $x_0$ if there exists a map $g : U \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to L(\mathbb{R}^n , \mathbb{R}^m)$ continuous at $x_0$ such that
$$
f(x) = f(x_0) + g(x)(x - x_0)
$$
I tried to prove the equivalence myself, but it's not as obvious as one the one-variable case (if it's true at all), since in the one variable case we could use the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is a field and $L(\mathbb{R} , \mathbb{R}) \cong \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What is the $g$ in your definition if $f(x)=x^2$?

Comment: @mrsamy $g(x)=\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}=x+x_0$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: you said "This is obviously just a restatement of the usual definition of a derivative" but there is no derivative in your definition. Do I miss something?// okay, you define the derivative as $g(x_0)$.

Comment: @mrsamy I added it to the post.

Comment: According to this definition a function like $x\mapsto x^2\chi_{\mathbb Q}$ is not differentiable at $x_0=0$.  It _implies_ the usual definition of differentiable at a point but is not equivalent to it.

Comment: It should be "$g$ is continuous at $x_0$", not on $U$.

Comment: @user10354138 you're right. I misremembered the definition. Nice catch.

Comment: Surely you need some sort of error term $o(\Vert x-x_0\rVert)$, in both the single-variable and multi-variable case?

Comment: @jlammy The goal of this definition is to let $g$ depend on $x$ so as to avoid having to include an error term. I know that $f(x + h) = f(x) + Ah + r(h)$ with $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{r(h)}{h} = 0$ is equivalent to the usual definition of the derivative. I'm trying to avoid having to include the $r(h)$ term by letting the linear transformation depend on $x$. Also, in the one variable case it works without the error term, as you can see by dividing both sides by $x - x_0$ and passing the limit. This works because $g$ can depend on $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One direction is clear: if such $g$ exists, then $g$ is approximately constant $g(x)=g(x_0)+o(1)$ so $f$ is approximately linear $f(x_0)+g(x)(x-x_0)=f(x_0)+g(x_0)(x-x_0)+o(\lVert x-x_0\rVert)$ which is the usual definition of $f$ being differentiable at $x_0$.

For the other direction, for $x\neq x_0$, we only know $g(x)$ on the linear span of $x-x_0$, and the easiest way to extend this to the whole of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is to make $g(x)(v)=f'(x_0)(v)$ for all $v\perp (x-x_0)$.  Then set $g(x_0)=f'(x_0)$ and it clearly works.

Comment: I've actually stipulated that $g(x)$ is linear on all of $\mathbb{R}^n$ in the hypothetical definition. Does that change your answer?

Comment: $g(x)$ is linear.  We use the splitting $\mathbb{R}^n=\operatorname{span}(x-x_0)\oplus(x-x_0)^\perp$ and define $g(x)$ on each piece.  In full, it is $$g(x)(v)=\frac{v\cdot(x-x_0)}{\lvert x-x_0\rvert}[f(x)-f(x_0)]+f'(x_0)(v-\frac{v\cdot(x-x_0)}{\lvert x-x_0\rvert^2}(x-x_0))$$ when $x\neq x_0$.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying. Then it seems that the definitions are equivalent. I do have some doubts about saying $g(x) = g(x_0) + o(1)$, but if this is a standard fact, then I'll accept your answer.

Comment: I looked it up and it seems like a valid argument to me. In your expression for $g$ shouldn't it be $\frac{v\cdot (x - x_0)}{| x- x_0 |^2} [f(x) - f(x_0 )]$? Great stuff by the way. I wasn't expecting you could "solve" for $g$, but it makes perfect sense in hindsight.

Comment: Yes, it should have a square in the denominator.